# How am I going to display data into an looped input field?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am trying to generate results for my quiz generator. My quiz generator has different categories where in I wanted to display separate results for each category. To display the results/scores, I looped the categories and make it as an input type=button. Data for my button came from **tbl_category**.

**SRPerCat.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","learning_assessment") or die("cannot connect to database!");
$sqlcat="select * from tbl_category;";
$rscat=mysqli_query($con,$sqlcat);
$rowscat=mysqli_fetch_array($rscat);
?>

<form action="SRPerCat.php" method="post">

<?php do{?>
<table border="1">
<tr>

<th><input class="submitbtnsSTARTEXAM" type="submit" name="categories" value="<?php echo $rowscat['category'];?>" /></th>

<th><input type="text" name="scores" value="/*What to put here???*/" /></th>
</tr>
</table>

<?php }while($rowscat=mysqli_fetch_array($rscat));?>
<br /><br /><input class="submitbtnsSTARTEXAM" type="submit" name="sendmyscore" value="VIEW MY SCORE PER AREA" />
</form>
```

What I want to happen is, when I click the button(individually) [for example: the value of button is "Math"], it will display the garnered score to the textfield beside it($_POST['scores'].

This is my query where the scores will be coming from.
Scores will be from **tbl_corrects**

```
if(isset($_POST['categories'])){
$countcat="select * from tbl_corrects where category='$_POST[categories]' and correctorwrong='CORRECT' and username='$_SESSION[user]';";
$countcatrs=mysqli_query($con,$countcat);
$countcatrows=mysqli_num_rows($countcatrs);
echo $countcatrows;
}
?>
```

The $countcatrows is the value that I want to appear in the text field beside the submit button(with the value of the category).

It's like, when I click the button(one by one), the score will appear beside each category(button).

Comment: Nobody can understand.

Comment: Sorry sir. I tried to explain it the clearest way. :|